# JavaScript/jQuery hangman Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

I'm making a hangman game, and I can't seem to get the game loop right. I'm trying to get it to run through the word, and replace the letter if it is the correct answer. Instead, it's:

- looping through the word
- if the guessed letter is located anywhere in the word
- it returns `index[0]`

I tried splitting the word, and working with the individual indexes, but if I can do it this way, I'd rather learn how to do that. Also, I'm still trying to figure out how to loop the hints! Thanks for your time!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var words = ["RUGRATS", "DOUG", "DARIA", "POKEMON", "RECESS", "ANAMANIACS", "CARMEN/SAN/DIEGO", "REN AND STIMPY", "THE SIMPSONS", "POWER RANGERS", "BEAVIS AND BUTTHEAD", "ROCKOS MODERN LIFE", "NINJA TURTLES", "MATILDA"]
  var chosenWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)]
  // var space = ''
  var underScores = [] //underscores
  var wrongGuesses = [] //store wrong guesses
  var guesses = 10 //guess max
  //replace 
  var wins = 0;
  $(".wins").html("WINS : " + wins)
  var hints = ["Gang of Babies", "Quail man's identity", "90's femenist", "Gotta Catch 'em all!", "playtime during school, not lunch", "They live in the WB tower", "Where in the world is...", "'It's log, log...", "Longest running cartoon.", "Morphin' time!", "'I need teepee for my bunghole'", "Friendly walabe", "Pizza lovin' turtles", "Girl Genius"]
  var hintLength = hints.length
  var getHint = $("#hintBtn")
  $(".hintBtn").on("click", function() {
    if (words[0] === chosenWord) {
      $("#hint").text(hints[0])
    } else if (words[1] === chosenWord) {
      $("#hint").text(hints[1])
    } else if (words[2] === chosenWord) {
      $("#hint").text(hints[2])
    } else if (words[3] === chosenWord) {
      $("#hint").text(hints[3])
    } else if (words[4] === chosenWord) {
      $("#hint").text(hints[4])
    } else if (words[5] === chosenWord) {
      $("#hint").text(hints[5])
    } else if (words[6] === chosenWord) {
      $("#hint").text(hints[6])
    } else if (words[7] === chosenWord) {
      $("#hint").text(hints[7])
    } else if (words[8] === chosenWord) {
      $("#hint").text(hints[8])
    } else if (words[9] === chosenWord) {
      $("#hint").text(hints[9])
    } else if (words[10] === chosenWord) {
      $("#hint").text(hints[10])
    } else if (words[11] === chosenWord) {
      $("#hint").text(hints[11])
    } else if (words[12] === chosenWord) {
      $("#hint").text(hints[12])
    } else if (words[13] === chosenWord) {
      $("#hint").text(hints[12])
    }
  })

  $("#newGame").on("click", function() {
    chosenWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)]
    underScores = []
    for (var i = 0; i < chosenWord.length; i++) {
      underScores.push("_ ")
    }
    guesses = 10
    $(".guessesLeft").html("You have " + guesses + " guesses left!")
    $(".display").html(underScores)
    $("#hint").html("Press the button to get a hint!")
    console.log("your random word is " + chosenWord)
  })

  if (guesses > 0) {
    $(document).on("keyup", function(event) {
      guess = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toUpperCase()
      // console.log(guess)
      if (chosenWord.indexOf(guess) > -1) {
        for (i = 0; i < chosenWord.length; i++) {
          if (chosenWord[i] = guess) {
            underScores[i] = chosenWord[i]
            console.log(underScores)
            underScores.join(" ")
            return
          }
        }
      } else {
        for (i = 0; i < chosenWord.length; i++) {
          if (chosenWord[i] != guess) {
            guesses--
            var wrongGuesses = guess
            $(".wrongGuesses").append(wrongGuesses)
            console.log(wrongGuesses)
            return
          }

        }
      }
    })
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bevan' rel='stylesheet'>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- main content -->
      <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="jumbotron">
          <h1>Hangman : 90's Cartoons & Movies!</h1>
          <h2>Press any key to get started!</h2>
          <!-- button for new word -->
          <button id="newGame">NEW GAME</button>
          <div class="wins"></div>
          <div class="losses"></div>

          <div class="display"></div>
          <div class="wrongGuesses"></div>
          <div class="guessesLeft"></div>
          <div id="buttons"></div>
          <button class="hintBtn">HINT!</button>
          <p id="hint"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="assets/javascript/game2.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close -- only two things need to be changed.

Your `if` statement was assigning instead of comparing. Change this:

```
if (chosenWord[i] = guess) {
```

to this:

```
if (chosenWord[i] == guess) {
```

Also, you need to refresh your HTML to show the correct letters when they are guessed. Add this line before returning after a correct guess:

```
$(".display").html(underScores)
```

*One thing to note:* your function was returning after the first instance of a correct letter. I removed the `return` statement so it would finish looping through the word, so it will populate the underscores for any instances of the correct letter.

Here's a working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var words = ["RUGRATS", "DOUG", "DARIA", "POKEMON", "RECESS", "ANAMANIACS", "CARMEN/SAN/DIEGO", "REN AND STIMPY", "THE SIMPSONS", "POWER RANGERS", "BEAVIS AND BUTTHEAD", "ROCKOS MODERN LIFE", "NINJA TURTLES", "MATILDA"]
  var chosenWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)]
  // var space = ''
  var underScores = [] //underscores
  var wrongGuesses = [] //store wrong guesses
  var guesses = 10 //guess max
  //replace 
  var wins = 0;
  $(".wins").html("WINS : " + wins)
  var hints = ["Gang of Babies", "Quail man's identity", "90's femenist", "Gotta Catch 'em all!", "playtime during school, not lunch", "They live in the WB tower", "Where in the world is...", "'It's log, log...", "Longest running cartoon.", "Morphin' time!", "'I need teepee for my bunghole'", "Friendly walabe", "Pizza lovin' turtles", "Girl Genius"]
  var hintLength = hints.length
  var getHint = $("#hintBtn")
  $(".hintBtn").on("click", function() {
    if (words[0] === chosenWord) {
      $("#hint").text(hints[0])
    } else if (words[1] === chosenWord) {
      $("#hint").text(hints[1])
    } else if (words[2] === chosenWord) {
      $("#hint").text(hints[2])
    } else if (words[3] === chosenWord) {
      $("#hint").text(hints[3])
    } else if (words[4] === chosenWord) {
      $("#hint").text(hints[4])
    } else if (words[5] === chosenWord) {
      $("#hint").text(hints[5])
    } else if (words[6] === chosenWord) {
      $("#hint").text(hints[6])
    } else if (words[7] === chosenWord) {
      $("#hint").text(hints[7])
    } else if (words[8] === chosenWord) {
      $("#hint").text(hints[8])
    } else if (words[9] === chosenWord) {
      $("#hint").text(hints[9])
    } else if (words[10] === chosenWord) {
      $("#hint").text(hints[10])
    } else if (words[11] === chosenWord) {
      $("#hint").text(hints[11])
    } else if (words[12] === chosenWord) {
      $("#hint").text(hints[12])
    } else if (words[13] === chosenWord) {
      $("#hint").text(hints[12])
    }
  })

  $("#newGame").on("click", function() {
    chosenWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)]
    underScores = []
    for (var i = 0; i < chosenWord.length; i++) {
      underScores.push("_ ")
    }
    guesses = 10
    $(".guessesLeft").html("You have " + guesses + " guesses left!")
    $(".display").html(underScores)
    $("#hint").html("Press the button to get a hint!")
    console.log("your random word is " + chosenWord)
  })

  if (guesses > 0) {
    $(document).on("keyup", function(event) {
      guess = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toUpperCase()
      // console.log(guess)
      if (chosenWord.indexOf(guess) > -1) {
        for (i = 0; i < chosenWord.length; i++) {
          if (chosenWord[i] == guess) {
            underScores[i] = chosenWord[i]
            console.log(underScores)
            underScores.join(" ")
            $(".display").html(underScores)
          }
        }
      } else {
        for (i = 0; i < chosenWord.length; i++) {
          if (chosenWord[i] != guess) {
            guesses--
            var wrongGuesses = guess
            $(".wrongGuesses").append(wrongGuesses)
            console.log(wrongGuesses)
            return
          }

        }
      }
    })
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bevan' rel='stylesheet'>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- main content -->
      <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="jumbotron">
          <h1>Hangman : 90's Cartoons & Movies!</h1>
          <h2>Press any key to get started!</h2>
          <!-- button for new word -->
          <button id="newGame">NEW GAME</button>
          <div class="wins"></div>
          <div class="losses"></div>

          <div class="display"></div>
          <div class="wrongGuesses"></div>
          <div class="guessesLeft"></div>
          <div id="buttons"></div>
          <button class="hintBtn">HINT!</button>
          <p id="hint"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="assets/javascript/game2.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the issue! It's a work in progress, but I couldn't move past this haha